# Splitting an array of points into multiple arrays that have a specific distance from each other

Tags: c#

I have an array of points that look like this (x,y):

```
6,12
6,13.25
6,14.5
6,15.75
6,17
6,18.25
18,12
18,13.25
18,14.5
18,15.75
18,17
18,18.25
```

This array represents a two, separate, series of points that are on a 1.25" offset from each other.  There is two series, but there can be [n] series, and I need to split them up into the appropriate number of arrays based on the specific offset like this:

```
6,12
6,13.25
6,14.5
6,15.75
6,17
6,18.25

18,12
18,13.25
18,14.5
18,15.75
18,17
18,18.25
```

The offset can be in the X or the Y, but not both.  I have been working on it for a little while now and am kind of stuck.

Edit

What I have tried so far, is to get a point in the array, and search for all points that are on the interval specified (getDist calculates the distance from one point to another):

```
foreach(Point firstPoint in points){
    foreach(Point nextPoint in points){
        if(isSame(firstPoint, nextPoint)
            continue;

        if(getDist(firstPoint, nextPoint) % 1.25 == 0){
            // add to new array
        }
    }
}

double getDist(Point p1, Point p2) => Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2.X - p1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p2.Y - p1.Y, 2));

bool isSame(Point p1, Point p2) => p1.X == p2.X && p1.Y == p2.Y;
```

The problem I run into is that this looks at all the points, then looks at them each one again creating a huge set of arrays.

Comment: I have edited my post to include this.

Comment: Please also include your `getDist` and `isSame` functions so we have a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks for all you responses, with them I was able to get this working.  I used something similar to this.  I can't share the exact code as there is code from my company that I can't share.  I get the points in a collection that is very similar to an array, and I HAVE to use them in this type of collection.

```
while(points.Length > 0){
    Point currentPoint = points[0];
    List<Point> selectedPoints = new List<Point>();

    selectedPoints.Add(currentPoint)

    for(int i = 1; i <= points.Length; i++){
        Point nextPoint = points[i];
        double dist = getDist(currentPoint, nextPoint);
        if(Math.Abs(dist % 1.25 - 0) < 1.19e-4){
            selectedPoints.Add(nextPoint);
        }
    }

    // remove selected points from all points
    // add them to my list of points that I needed
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Using linq :

```
            decimal[,] data = {{6,12}, {6,13.25M}, {6, 14.5M}, {6,15.75M}, {6,17}, {6,18.25M},
                                  {18,12},{18,13.25M}, {18,14.5M},{18,15.75M},{18,17},{18,18.25M}};

            var groups = data.Cast<decimal>()
                .Select((x, i) => new { num = x, index = i })
                .GroupBy(x => x.index / 2)
                .Select(x => new decimal[] { x.FirstOrDefault().num, x.LastOrDefault().num })
                .GroupBy(x => x.FirstOrDefault())
                .Select(x => x.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it, but instead of storing the results in arrays, I used lists (the code might need improvements though):

```
List<List<PointF>> splitted_list = new List<List<PointF>>();

float x = 0;
float y = 0;

float offsetX = 0;
float offsetY = 0;

foreach(PointF p in points)
{
    if (splitted_list.Count() > 0)
    {
        if (splitted_list.Last().Count() >= 2 && (p.X - x != offsetX || p.Y - y != offsetY))
        {
            List<PointF> list_points = new List<PointF>();
            list_points.Add(p);
            splitted_list.Add(list_points);
        }
        else
        {
            splitted_list.Last().Add(p);
            offsetX = p.X - x;
            offsetY = p.Y - y;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        List<PointF> list_points = new List<PointF>();
        list_points.Add(p);
        splitted_list.Add(list_points);
    }

    x = p.X;
    y = p.Y;
}
```

Everytime one of the offsets changes, I create a new list and I add it to my "list of lists" (it works regardless of the offset's value).

So the result is a list of series of points. If you HAVE to use those series as arrays of points, you can simply convert the lists to arrays by using the method ToArray().

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>()
    {
        new PointF(6, 12),
        new PointF(6, 13.25f),
        new PointF(6, 14.5f),
        new PointF(6, 15.75f),
        new PointF(6, 17),
        new PointF(6, 18.25f),
        new PointF(18, 12),
        new PointF(18, 13.25f),
        new PointF(18, 14.5f),
        new PointF(18, 15.75f),
        new PointF(18, 17),
        new PointF(18, 18.25f)
    };

    var result = new List<List<PointF>>();
    int i, j = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!IsInRange(points[i], points[i - 1]))
        {
            result.Add(points.GetRange(j, i - j));
            j = i;
        }
    }
    result.Add(points.GetRange(j, i - j));
}

static bool IsInRange(PointF a, PointF b) => Math.Abs(a.X + a.Y - b.X - b.Y) <= 1.25f;
```